# in R, expand a function for vectors

Tags: r

I created a function for simples characters... my function completes a character with zeros while the number of character is less(strictly) that 4.

```
completamento<- function(c)
{
  while( nchar(c)< 4)
   {
     c<- paste0("0",c)
   }
return(c)
}
```

When I do

```
completamento(c="aaa")
> "0aaa"
```

It is OK...

But when I try to put the argument of the function to be one vector, there is some wrong..

```
completamento(c=c("aaa", "bb"))
Warning messages:
1: In while (nchar(c) < 4) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In while (nchar(c) < 4) { :
   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

There is some way to vectorize this function?

Comment: A quick fix `completamento<- function(c) {
  for (i in 1:length(c)) {
    if(nchar(c[i]) < 4) {
     c[i] <- paste0("0", c[i])
    }
  }
return(c)
}   `

Comment: It's a solution. But I allways avoid to use the looping for in my scripts..

Comment: @Vasco - a `while()` statement is just a loop too.

Comment: Yes.. there is some way to avoid the while function? Or in other words, I would to like use the minimal loop functions...

Comment: Some one put this solution and deleted it: completamento <- Vectorize(completamento, USE.NAMES = F)